# Design a JFrame in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, intellij-idea, jframe

Trying out IntelliJ IDEA, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to design a JFrame. In Eclipse, the WindowBuilder would create a new sub-class of JFrame and generate Java Source Code. I have changed IDEA's settings to generate to java source code, but IDEA appears to like generating JPanels and setting them as the Root Pane of an instance of JFrame. Am I over-looking something or is this a design choice?

Answer (score 6):

It's a design choice, you need to write your own code creating a top level frame, then you can add a panel created in the GUI designer to it. The same affects the inability to design JMenu and status bar.

If you are looking for a more advanced GUI designer for IDEA (and other IDEs), check out [JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/).

Comment: If you're new to IntelliJ, you'll also need this information:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396738/making-a-hello-world-app-in-a-form-in-intellij

Comment: JFormDesigner is commercial payware :(